# Str_replace solution needed

Tags: php

Currently I'm running into an issue, I'm parsing some data from a website and the image urls it returns have different resolution values at the end of them examples being as following.. `-500x330` and `-660x330`.

Currently I am using this method of removing one of them.

```
$image = $html2->find('meta[property=og:image]',0);
$image = $image->content;

$img = str_replace('-500x330', '', $image);
```

How could I use a similar method, to remove **ALL** of the resolution possibilities?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$img = preg_replace('/-\d{3}x\d{3}/', '', $image);
```

But if you have and two/one digits then pattern must be:

```
/-\d{1,3}x\d{1,3}/
```

Comment: If you have more than 3 digits you could use
    `/-\d+x\d+/`

Comment: @akrys Vin example have 3 digits only. But, yes, your comment may be useful. Maybe for NASA space photos with 10k resolution ))

Comment: It should only give an idea, that you're not restricted to a certain amount of digits.

Comment: @akrys just relax it's sarcasm ))